# Node.js and Sockets for Browser and Flash

Tags: flash, http, sockets, node.js, socket.io

doing a project where the deviceorientation-data from smartphones get transfered to a socketserver, and from there to a flash-application.
Now creating a http-server with nodejs wasn't too hard, and connecting from a smartphone via browser and transfering the data with socket.io worked fine.
The problem comes with flash, i couldn't manage to connect my flash application to the http-server running socket.io. I figured out when i run a node tcp-server connecting from flash is no problem, but i have no more session management and i can't connect from the browser anymore.
I would be very happy about some idea/advice, really got stuck here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I strongly suspect socket.io wasn't really designed to talk to arbitrary Flash objects as it uses/embeds its own object to simulate websockets for browsers that do not support them (among other options).

You might look at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec which describes the protocol socket.io uses to communicate between client and server and https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node-client which simulates a variety of socket.io clients.